# Error while displaying the date and grabbing the month from the date

Tags: asp.net, mysql, date

By getting the date of my server, and when I trying to obtain the month part of the date, it gave this error.

Before that I used Windows 7, it works fine. After upgrading to Windows 8, it gave this error:

I think I found my problem which is when i try to do this:

```
fncFmtDate("19-12-2012","%d-%b-%Y")
```

the output I got is:

```
19-12?-2012
```

It supposed to show Abbreviated month name (Dec) but it displays the integer of the month and a question mark at the back (12?).

Sincerely need the pro helps.

Comment: What are those replacement symbols doing in your string?

Comment: I was trying to  assign myFormmatDate = fncFmtDate(strDate,"%d-%b-%Y")    ,when i response.write (myFormatDate), it display 26-12�-2012

Comment: Please link to or provide the source code for `fncFmtDate`. Also, are you sure [tag:asp.net] and [tag:mysql] are the correct tags?

Comment: the link for fncfmtdate is http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/cust.date.asp

Comment: That function is not for ASP.Net.  You'd be much better off not using it and going with the built-in ToString methods that are part of the DateTime object.